# Mule-Security(3.8) : how to custom the RoleVoter to implement our decision

Tags: mule

the configuration is below.I want to change to the way that must be named ROLE_,how should I do?

```
<spring:beans>
        <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
          <ss:authentication-provider>
            <ss:user-service id="userService">
              <ss:user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
              <ss:user name="anon" password="anon" authorities="ROLE_ANON" />
            </ss:user-service>
          </ss:authentication-provider>
        </ss:authentication-manager>
      </spring:beans>

      <mule-ss:security-manager>
          <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
      </mule-ss:security-manager>

      <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />

      <flow name="SpringExample">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
          <logger level="INFO" message="## received" doc:name="Logger"/>
          <http:basic-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>     
        <logger level="INFO" message="## passed security" doc:name="Logger"/>
      </flow>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear .. what actually you are trying to do ?